# Where can I find a good treeview control for Flex that supports checkboxes?

Tags: apache-flex, treeview, checkbox

To my best knowledge the out-of-the-box Flex 3 treeview control does not support checkboxes.  Where can I find a good treeview control that supports checkboxes on any and all nodes. I would prefer open source software but commercial components are not out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out the following  http://www.sephiroth.it/test/components/flex2/treecheckbox/test.swf

http://www.sephiroth.it/index.php

http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2006/09/flex2_again_checkbox_3state.php

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1047969#

Enjoy